# Extending Dictionary of key : String value:Array in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, protocols, extension-methods

How can I extend a Swift Dictionary of type `[String:[Double]]`?

What is the protocol/Class_Type to be conformed by the Value while extending the dictionary?

[ P.S : In this Extension I want to return all the keys whose value arrays contains a particular element(Double) that is send to the function.]

Comment: So you want to filter a dictionary to find keys that contain a particular double value?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Yes, I know how to Find the keys, But Primarily I need to know How Extend this type of Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries have two generic elements `Key` and `Value` that need constraining when you create your extension.

You can do that like so:

```
public extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == [Double] { }
```

Comment: Thank You, This Works fine!

Comment: @SivaAthi if you've found an answer that resolves your question, try to remember to mark it as the accepted answer! You'll get a small reputation boost, as well as helping other readers with the same problem get to the solution faster!

Comment: Sorry that I forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to do that like below:

```
let dictData = ["a":[1.0,2.0,3.0],
                "b":[1.0,112.0,3.0],
                "c":[7.0,12.0,3.0]]

let filterData = dictData.filter({$0.value.contains(1)})
print(filterData.keys) //output: ["a", "b"]
```

You can itrate this array like this:

```
 for keys in filterData.keys.makeIterator() {
      print(keys)
 }
```

Or you can directly access like this:

```
filterData.keys.first
```

Comment: yes, That Works!! But also I would like to know how to extend this type of Dictionary, Primarily.

Comment: Yeah, Taken care of. Thank you for the Update :)